# Can't save as CSV in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have Excel 2007 and I can't save as CSV. Under "Save as type", it's just not even an option. Why is this?

Comment: is not under the "Save as type" when you go to "Save As > Other Formats"?

Comment: No, it's not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted the correct answer but then they apparently deleted it. The solution was to click the "save" icon.

That worked, but ONLY after I went into Excel Options > Save and picked CSV.

It also only works when the document has not already been saved. So if you're converting a file, you have to copy and paste the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

For some this may be the case as I found I just wasnt scrolling down enough!

Save as > Other Formats > scroll down in the "Save as type" box! You should find it.